# I didn't think this question wasn't constructive, why am I listed as voting that way?

Tags: support

I voted to close [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47178/do-you-know-this-colorpicker/47183) as "too localized".    As far as I am concerned, it is a valid, constructive question.  It has a right answer (and I was even able to find it).

Nobody else is going to be looking for that color picker from that screenshot again.  My answer is only going to help that one user.  So, after I answered the question, I voted to close as "too localized".  In my opinion "too localized" is the correct closed reason, and "not constructive" is off base.

However, the question now says:

> closed as not constructive by bybe, Su', Stephen Ostermiller, John Conde♦ yesterday

Why am I listed for that close reason (and can I remove myself from the list)?

Answer (score 4):

This happens when a moderator closes the question, so if you voted too localized and some people voted construction then we are all merged into one category.

It depends how you look at it really, I consider the question to be both too localized and nonconstructive, as your right in saying its unlikely to help others but on another note - it's also extremely hard to identify generic looking color pickers. The question in question would of been much more constructive had it contained HTML snippets obtained using firebug on the element or even a link would of been helpful. For this reason I understand both reasons to be valid, I believe you can only close a question based on one choice, and it'll merge all votes together.

Personally I don't see it being a major problem, the question can voted to re-open, additionally your answer will remain since the moderators should or do not delete questions with good answers as per FAQ of stack sites even though the question may be closed.

However maybe your get some moderator insight on this.

Comment: bybe is correct -- when a moderator chooses a close reason, or a majority do, that close reason is listed as ***the*** reasons for the closure, regardless of how the others voted. In essence: you, Stephen, voted to close, but the close reason was decided by committee.

Answer (score 3):

There can be just one close reason, and sometimes it is not easy for a moderator to decide.

This is what I got once on WordPress Stack Exchange:

[image]

You cannot satisfy everybody.